# Customize and managing tables in Power Query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, business-intelligence, m

I'm trying to predict (based on simple average) energy consumption untill the end of the month.
I have a table with accumulated energy consumption of my plant until yesterday.

[Data Structure in Power Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6ZUc.png)
'Energy Meter Code', 'Date', 'Hour of the Day', 'Day of the week = Dia Semana', and 'Consumption (MWh)' are the most important columns in this table.

I understand my next step is to:

1. Create a table with the rest of the days of current month
2. Calculate average consumption based on different parameters (day of the week, hour of the day, etc) for each hour of the following days
3. Merge two tables and it's done

However, I don't know how to customize tables in Power Query (syntax problem).
Is there any simple way where I may create dynamic table considering the missing days till the end of the month? Or even  better, considering how many hours do we have

Thanks in advance for sharing your experience

Comment: See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/list-dates

Comment: You have a long way to go ....